# Getting SAML Request is invalid error while requesting into OpenAm from SP?

Tags: tomcat7, single-sign-on, keystore, openam, onelogin

We have an Enterprise App acting as SP (Service Provider) and an OpenAm acting as IDP (Identity Provider).

Generated a metadata from SP and imported into OpenAm

**Metadata file**

```
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"  ID="_602b5e40-99ef-0134-def1-4d6af9854785" entityID="https://<site>/sso_auth/metadata">
<md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>
cert
</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>
<md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>
cert
</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>
<md:SingleLogoutService ResponseLocation="https://<site>/sso_auth/logout" Location="https://<site>/sso_auth/logout" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"/>
<md:NameIDFormat>
urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified
</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:AssertionConsumerService isDefault="true" index="0" Location="https://<site>/sso_auth/consume_saml" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>
</md:SPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

SP digitally signs and initiate a request to OpenAm then I am getting **'The SAML Request is invalid'** error.

Singed SP's Request

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest AssertionConsumerServiceURL='https://<site>/sso_auth/consume_saml'
    Destination='http://<openam>/openam_12.0.0/SSOPOST/metaAlias/idp'
    ID='_2eeaae10-99f0-0134-def1-4d6af9854785' IssueInstant='2016-12-01T12:32:44Z' Version='2.0'
    xmlns:saml='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion'
    xmlns:samlp='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol'>
    <saml:Issuer>https://<site>/sso_auth/metadata</saml:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'>
        <ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#'/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm='XMLSecurity::Document::RSA_SHA1'/>
            <ds:Reference URI='#_2eeaae10-99f0-0134-def1-4d6af9854785'>
                <ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature'/>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#'><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList='#default samlp saml ds xs xsi md'
                        xmlns:ec='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#'/></ds:Transform>
                </ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1'/>
                <ds:DigestValue>n4a4wAkD84V7Qm+8MTeYcJzsAxI=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>
            signature
        </ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>
                    cert
                </ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature><samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate='true'
        Format='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified'/></samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

I am getting bellow error

[image]

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: The error says "Invalid Signature" and I don't see any keys in yr sp metadata. Is this really the correct MD file (as imported)? Check OpenAM debug log file "Federation" for more info on why the Fed fails.

Comment: In metadata we will share only public key (certificate) with IDP but while initiating the request to IDP we will sign the request (ds:SignatureValue).

Comment: It seems that the private key used to sign the quest does not "belong" to the public key provided in the metadata 

<md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>
cert
</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>

As Steffo proposed, please set debug level to 'message' and check "Federation" debug log.

Comment: I checked the debug log, it is showing 'Invalid signature in Request'. I Think i am getting an error because of a self-signed certificate which is used for signing.